# How can I debug an iOS Selenium test in Python

Tags: python, ios, selenium, debugging, appium

I'm trying to run an iOS Selenium test in debug mode. I'm using Appium, an iOS simulator (Xcode), and writing the tests in Python.

Once the code reach my breakpoint I can see all the variables, but few seconds later, instead of seeing their values I get the following exception:

`A session is either terminated or not started`

This is happening even though I can see the simulator is still running.

I've tried looking online but couldn't find a solution, Can you please help? 
Thanks!

Comment: Check your appium server log. There will be full error log

Answer (score 0):

You might want to increase `newCommandTimeout` [Desired Capability value](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/) to something which will allow you to inspect the elements values. The relevant code line to increase the timeout to 5 minutes would be:

```
desired_caps['newCommandTimeout'] = '300'
```

Full initialization routine just in case:

```
from appium import webdriver

desired_caps = {}
desired_caps['platformName'] = 'iOS'
desired_caps['platformVersion'] = '12.3'
desired_caps['automationName'] = 'xcuitest'
desired_caps['deviceName'] = 'iPhone SE'
desired_caps['newCommandTimeout'] = '300'

driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
```

This way Appium will wait for a new command from the client (your code) for 5 minutes prior to considering the client idle and terminating the session, it should be enough to enable debugging, feel free to increase more if needed.

You can also consider switching to [Appium Studio](https://experitest.com/mobile-test-automation/appium-studio/) which makes your life easier when it comes to inspecting the mobile layout, managing iOS devices/provisioning profiles, generating unique XPath locators for elements automatically and having an [extra set of Desired Capabilities](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TC/Additional+Server+Capabilities) allowing you to faster deal with edge cases